# Running a JAVA application - how are "trusted" certificate roots managed there?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, truststore

long story short - I need to validate XML signature, and one of the steps is to validate that PUBLIC certificate which was used to sign XML is issued by one of the knows roots.

This question is exactly the same as mine: [How to check if public X509Certificate is trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112241/how-to-check-if-public-x509certificate-is-trusted) - but the problem with the answer is that I do not want to "hardcode" any trust store files and passwords like they do:

```
 final File file = new File("C:\\TMP\\jssecacerts");
 InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
 KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
 //String password = "";
 //keystore.load(inStream, password.toCharArray());
 keystore.load(inStream, null);
```

I was hoping I can reuse the default, built-in `jre/lib/security/cacerts` file which is shipped with every JAVA installation. So I tried

```
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, null);
```

but it comes up empty.

The questions are as follows:

1. Please confirm JAVA loads `jre/lib/security/cacerts` file into memory every time I run a JAVA program. I find it hard to believe it does not - otherwise how all HTTPS communications would work?
2. How do I use this file to validate certificates? Or to simplify - how can I get access to trusted certificates KeyStore so I can apply validation logic?

Comment: There's a difference between the JVM TrustStore and KeyStore.
Passing in -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore specifies the keystore file.
Passing in -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore specifies the truststore file to use to validate client certificates.
The TrustStore holds the certificates of external systems that you trust, while the KeyStore holds your application’s certificates.

Comment: right - so is there a way to iterate through DEFAULT trust store certificates? Or is there an API to "validate" a certificate against default trust store?

Comment: Ah, I see. You stumped me, but I did find this and my gut tells me there seems to be a way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747164/how-to-check-if-x509-certificate-is-already-in-the-java-trust-store-programatica
Plus, the Java documentation shows a getPublicKey() method. Create an Enumeration<String> of the aliases() of the the KeyStore, loop through it and check if any of the X509s getPublicKey() aliases match.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I saw that post. But they use explicitly hardcoded password to open the trust store and I was hoping to avoid that..